# RedirectToAction from inside [HttpPost] to [HttpGet] - parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Code below:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(string id="")
{
    // ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string itemId="", EditViewModel viewModel)
{
    // ...

    RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = itemId });
}
```

returns an error: `"Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters"`.

I assume it's trying to redirect to [HttpPost] action.

How to redirect to [HttpGet] action?

I'm trying to implement Save functionality where it will save the edit and reload the form with new values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error message is clear...

... if you know that an optional parameter is a parameter with a default value (empty string in your case)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel viewModel, string itemId="")
{
    // ...

    RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = itemId });
}
```

and you're done

Comment: That's still Redirecting to [HttpPost]. It's just not complaining.

Comment: Hmm, is itemId a part of your viewModel ?